# How can I keep symbols loaded that don't change

Tags: c++, debug-symbols, visual-studio-debugging

I'm trying to speed up my debug iterations of a plugin. The host application is quite large and there are some hundred symbols from the OS and the main application. Only one .dll and one .pdb changes but it seems to have to reload every symbol from disk on demand. The launch times before I hit my breakpoint is almost five minutes. Running in release should be under one minute.

Things I've already tried:

- **Removing other unused .dll's** : helped but unpredictable results
- **Edit and Continue:** this worked "great" in the past. It doesn't work in this version of the host application. This might be due to some .net c++/cli wrapper for parts of the product (not related to the part I'm using)
- **Not using symbols:** not a great debug experience for 60% of cases.
- **Leave program running, just *unload* my .dll:** Unsupported since dependencies are unpredictable.

***Any recommendations for speeding up my workflow?***

Specs:

- **OS:** Windows 7 64bit
- **IDE/Debugger:** visual studio 2010 sp1
- **language:** c++
- **crt version:** sometimes *v90*, sometimes *v100* depending on the version of the host app.
- **using ms symbol server:** yes
- **edit and continue:** broken
- **Application Startup time:** 4-5mins
- **total count in modules window:** 589!

Comment: I also detected about 20 seconds worth of the time is in loading symbols for another plugin (that I sometimes need) that have no pdb's just exports.

Answer (score 0):

Use a Ramdisk and store the frequently-accessed symbols on it.

Comment: I might try this to synthesize my desired outcome. I'm not sure if the issue is loading the file from disk or some other transform in memory.

Answer (score 0):

Some other things you can try

1. Declare an environment variable called `_NO_DEBUG_HEAP=1`. [Very useful for a large application](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/401862/slow-deallocation-in-debug-mode-on-vista) that do lot of heap allocations
2. Avoid loading the MS symbols by default. You only need it once in a while in which case I just Right Mouse Button in the callstack window and pick **Load symbols from -> Symbol Path or Microsoft Symbol server**
3. See if you can upgrade to a SSD hard disk.